# How to add/edit values in an IndexedTable?

Tags: dataframe, julia

How to add or edit values in an IndexedTable? From [the documentation](https://juliacomputing.github.io/JuliaDB.jl/stable/basics/) I understood that IndexedTable object itself is immutable but not the underlying data, so I "understand" why something like this doesn't work, but I don't know how to obtain a new IndexedTable with the new data:

```
myTable = ndsparse((
             region      = ["US","US","US","US","EU","EU","EU","EU"],
             product     = ["apple","apple","banana","banana","apple","apple","banana","banana"],
             year        = [2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010]
           ),(
             production  = [3.3,3.2,2.3,2.1,2.7,2.8,1.5,1.3],
             consumption = [4.3,7.4,2.5,9.8,3.2,4.3,6.5,3.0]
          ))
myTable["EU","banana",2011] = (2.5, 7.5) # ERROR: type Tuple has no field region
myTable["EU","banana",2012] = (2.5, 7.5) # ERROR: type Tuple has no field region
myTable["EU","banana",2011] = (production = 2.5, consumption = 7.5) # ERROR: type Tuple has no field region
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the functionality you want is under JuliaDB's `Base.merge`.

[merge(a::NDSparse, a::NDSparse; agg)](https://juliacomputing.github.io/JuliaDB.jl/stable/api/#Base.merge-Tuple%7BUnion%7BIndexedTable,%20NDSparse%7D,Any%7D)

> Merge rows of a with rows of b. To keep unique keys, the value from b
>   takes priority. A provided function agg will aggregate values from a
>   and b that have the same key(s).
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> a = table((x = 1:5, y = rand(5)); pkey = :x)
> b = table((x = 6:10, y = rand(5)); pkey = :x)
> merge(a, b)
>
> a = ndsparse([1,3,5], [1,2,3])
> b = ndsparse([2,3,4], [4,5,6])
> merge(a, b)
> merge(a, b; agg = (x,y) -> x)
> ```

Working example based on your question:

```
# tested on Julia 1.0.4
julia> using JuliaDB
julia> myTable = ndsparse((
                    region      = ["US","US","US","US","EU","EU","EU","EU"],
                    product     = ["apple","apple","banana","banana","apple","apple","banana","banana"],
                    year        = [2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010,2011,2010]
                  ),(
                    production  = [3.3,3.2,2.3,2.1,2.7,2.8,1.5,1.3],
                    consumption = [4.3,7.4,2.5,9.8,3.2,4.3,6.5,3.0]
                 ))
3-d NDSparse with 8 values (2 field named tuples):
region  product   year │ production  consumption
───────────────────────┼────────────────────────
"EU"    "apple"   2010 │ 2.8         4.3
"EU"    "apple"   2011 │ 2.7         3.2
"EU"    "banana"  2010 │ 1.3         3.0
"EU"    "banana"  2011 │ 1.5         6.5 # Note the old value
"US"    "apple"   2010 │ 3.2         7.4
"US"    "apple"   2011 │ 3.3         4.3
"US"    "banana"  2010 │ 2.1         9.8
"US"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.3         2.5

julia> updated_myTable = ndsparse((
                    region      = ["EU"],
                    product     = ["banana"],
                    year        = [2011]
                  ),(
                    production  = [2.5], # new values here
                    consumption = [7.5]
                 ))
3-d NDSparse with 1 values (2 field named tuples):
region  product   year │ production  consumption
───────────────────────┼────────────────────────
"EU"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.5         7.5

julia> newTable = merge(updated_myTable, myTable, agg = (x,y) -> x)
3-d NDSparse with 8 values (2 field named tuples):
region  product   year │ production  consumption
───────────────────────┼────────────────────────
"EU"    "apple"   2010 │ 2.8         4.3
"EU"    "apple"   2011 │ 2.7         3.2
"EU"    "banana"  2010 │ 1.3         3.0
"EU"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.5         7.5 # Note the updated values here!
"US"    "apple"   2010 │ 3.2         7.4
"US"    "apple"   2011 │ 3.3         4.3
"US"    "banana"  2010 │ 2.1         9.8
"US"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.3         2.5
```

Note how the `agg` function prefers the keys from the first parameter given a collision.

One other hacky way to do it, is edit the data elements directly after discovering the right index.

```
julia> i = findfirst(isequal((region = "EU", product = "banana", year = 2011)), myTable.index)
4

julia> myTable.data[i]
(production = 1.5, consumption = 6.5)

julia> myTable.data[i] = (production = 2.5, consumption = 7.5)
(production = 2.5, consumption = 7.5)

julia> myTable
3-d NDSparse with 8 values (2 field named tuples):
region  product   year │ production  consumption
───────────────────────┼────────────────────────
"EU"    "apple"   2010 │ 2.8         4.3
"EU"    "apple"   2011 │ 2.7         3.2
"EU"    "banana"  2010 │ 1.3         3.0
"EU"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.5         7.5 # Note the updated values here!
"US"    "apple"   2010 │ 3.2         7.4
"US"    "apple"   2011 │ 3.3         4.3
"US"    "banana"  2010 │ 2.1         9.8
"US"    "banana"  2011 │ 2.3         2.5
```

Hope that helps.